# systemctl --enable enables socket instead of service

Tags: systemd

As it is common, `lxd` provides two systemd units: `lxd.socket` and `lxd.service`. When `lxd.socket` is started, it starts `lxd.service` as soon as any application (such as `lxc`) tries to access the lxd daemon.

I would like `lxd` to start on boot, without having to run any command. However, when I try to enable `lxd.service`, it enables `lxd.socket` instead:

```
# systemctl enable lxd.service
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/lxd.socket → /usr/lib/systemd/system/lxd.socket.
```

What is going on here? How can I enable `lxd.service`?

---

The system is running Fedora 39. These are the unit files:

`/usr/lib/systemd/system/lxd.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=LXD - main daemon
After=network-online.target openvswitch-switch.service lxcfs.service lxd.socket
Requires=network-online.target lxcfs.service lxd.socket
Documentation=man:lxd(1)

[Service]
Environment=LXD_DOCUMENTATION=/usr/share/doc/lxd-doc/html
Environment=LXD_OVMF_PATH=/usr/share/edk2/ovmf
Environment=LXD_UI=/usr/share/lxd-ui/ui
ExecStart=/usr/bin/lxd --group lxd
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/lxd waitready --timeout=600
KillMode=process
TimeoutStartSec=600s
TimeoutStopSec=30s
Restart=on-failure
LimitNOFILE=1048576
LimitNPROC=infinity
TasksMax=infinity

[Install]
Also=lxd-containers.service lxd.socket
```

`/usr/lib/systemd/system/lxd.socket`:

```
[Unit]
Description=LXD - unix socket
Documentation=man:lxd(1)

[Socket]
ListenStream=/var/lib/lxd/unix.socket
SocketGroup=lxd
SocketMode=0660
Service=lxd.service

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

Comment: On what platform (ubuntu? fedora? something else?) are you running lxd? It would help to know what the lxd service unit looks like.

Comment: I've updated the question with those details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing is driven by the `Also` keyword in the service unit, which you can read about [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.unit.html#Also=).

Because the service unit does not specify a `WantedBy` (or `RequiredBy`) directive in the `[Install]` section, this `Also` means effectively "instead": when you `systemctl enable lxd.service`, instead enable `lxd-containers.service` and `lxd.socket`.

You could try simply adding `WantedBy=default.target` to the `[Install]` section, so that the `lxd` service is started automatically at boot. Don't forget to `systemctl daemon-reload` after editing the unit (or after creating a drop-in config).

Comment: Brilliant, it worked! I added that `[Install]` section to `/etc/systemd/system/lxd.service.d/override.conf`.